# (IRC) How to register on FreeNode using HexChat when I get disconnected immediately?

Tags: irc

I have been trying to get on #httpd on FreeNode. From the instructions [here](https://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration), I understand I am supposed to enter `/msg NickServ REGISTER password youremail@example.com` using my info instead. 
I can't enter this because I get disconnected as soon as I try to connect to Freenode. I have attempted to connect to the #freenode channel to ask for help but again, I just get disconected.

It goes like this every time:

```
...
Cycling to next server in freenode...
* Disconnected ()
* Looking up irc.freenode.net
* Connecting to chat.freenode.net (162.213.39.42:6667)
* Connected. Now logging in.
* *** Looking up your hostname...
* *** Checking Ident
* *** Found your hostname
* *** No Ident response
* Capabilities supported: account-notify extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix sasl
* Capabilities requested: account-notify extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix sasl 
* Capabilities acknowledged: account-notify extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix sasl 
* Authenticating via SASL as will (PLAIN)
* SASL authentication failed
* *** Notice -- You need to identify via SASL to use this server
* Closing Link: gateway/vpn/privateinternetaccess/account (SASL access only)
* Disconnected (Remote host closed socket)
 Cycling to next server in freenode...
* Disconnected ()
* Looking up chat.freenode.net
* Connecting to chat.freenode.net (149.56.134.238:6697)
* * Subject: /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
* * Issuer: /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
* * Subject: /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
* * Issuer: /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
* * Subject: /CN=cherryh.freenode.net
* * Issuer: /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
* * Certification info:
*   Subject:
*     CN=cherryh.freenode.net
*   Issuer:
*     C=US
*     O=Let's Encrypt
*     CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*   Public key algorithm: rsaEncryption (4096 bits)
*   Sign algorithm sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Valid since Apr 24 05:02:00 2017 GM to Jul 23 05:02:00 2017 GM
* * Cipher info:
*   Version: TLSv1/SSLv3, cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256 bits)
* Connected. Now logging in.
* *** Looking up your hostname...
* *** Checking Ident
* *** Found your hostname
* *** No Ident response
* Capabilities supported: account-notify extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix sasl
* Capabilities requested: account-notify extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix sasl 
* Capabilities acknowledged: account-notify extended-join identify-msg multi-prefix sasl 
* Authenticating via SASL as will (PLAIN)
* SASL authentication failed
* *** Notice -- You need to identify via SASL to use this server
* Closing Link: gateway/vpn/privateinternetaccess/account (SASL access only)
* Disconnected (Remote host closed socket)
 Cycling to next server in freenode...
...
```

Just keeps doing that over and over and over.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/irc/comments/3xk7zj/little_help_connecting_to_freenode_via_a_vpn/) on the `/r/irc` subreddit:

> SASL is a method of identifying to network services, which you can only do if you've already registered. If you don't have a registered nick or account on Freenode, you can't connect with SASL. You'll need to connect normally first and register, and then use SASL for future connections.

Which means you've basically got a chicken and the egg problem if you're connecting from one of the IP blocks blacklisted by Freenode, which require SASL to connect. Most of the AWS IP space and several ISPs are in this blacklist.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Connect from a non-blacklisted IP space to register your nick, then connect via SASL normally.
2. Connect and register via the web at https://webchat.freenode.net/ and proceed as above.

Comment: This answer could be improved with suggestions for a home user whose home IP is blacklisted to obtain access to "a non-blacklisted IP space".

Comment: @DamianYerrick I think details on using a proxy or VPN to circumvent IP blocks would be a bit out of scope for this answer, and could be found easily anyway with a bit of searching. This is also where the second solution of registering using the web chat comes in.